# When I press the back button or make the gesture to go back, it does not reload the ViewPager properly

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewpager

I'm using Navigation Component, although I don't think that's the problem. The thing is that when I'm in a fragment that contains a ViewPager and I navigate to another one, when I go back using the back button or the gesture of the mobile phone, it returns to the previous fragment but it stops showing the ViewPager. I'll leave you my code for that fragment:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var homeFragmentViewModel: HomeFragmentViewModel

    private var listAdapter: FlagsListAdapter? = null
    private var regionName: String? = null

    private val hashtagLabel: TextView by lazy { home_fragment__label__hashtag }
    private val flagViewPager: ViewPager by lazy { home_fragment__viewpager__countries }
    private val countryLabel: TextView by lazy { home_fragment__label__country_name }
    private val showCasesButton: Button by lazy { home_fragment__button__country_cases }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): HomeFragment {
            return HomeFragment()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        homeFragmentViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeFragmentViewModel::class.java)

        homeFragmentViewModel.getCountriesFlagLiveData().observeOnce(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            setFlagsAdapter(it)
        })

        showCasesButton.setOnClickListener {
            val actionNavigateToShowCasesFragment = HomeFragmentDirections.navigateHomeFragmentToShowCasesFragment()
            regionName?.let { regionName -> actionNavigateToShowCasesFragment.regionName = regionName }
            it.findNavController().navigate(actionNavigateToShowCasesFragment)
        }

        setFormatHashtag()
    }


    private fun setFlagsAdapter(flagModelList: List<FlagModel>) {
        listAdapter = context?.let {
            FlagsListAdapter(
                flagModelList,
                it
            )
        }

        flagViewPager.adapter = listAdapter
        flagViewPager.setPadding(130, 0, 130, 0)

        flagViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
                Toast.makeText(GlobalApplication.getContextFromApplication, "Hola", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onPageScrolled(
                position: Int,
                positionOffset: Float,
                positionOffsetPixels: Int
            ) {
                countryLabel.text = ""
                countryLabel.text = flagModelList[position].regionName
                regionName = flagModelList[position].regionName
            }

            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                countryLabel.text = flagModelList[position].regionName            }
        })
    }

    private fun setFormatHashtag() {
        val text = getString(R.string.home_fragment_hashtag)
        val spannableString = SpannableString(text)
        val foregroundColorSpan = context?.let {
            ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(it, R.color.hashtagColor))
        }
        spannableString.setSpan(foregroundColorSpan, 0, 8, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

        hashtagLabel.text = spannableString
    }
}
```

This is my activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val navigationBottomBar by lazy { activity_main__navigation_view__bottom_bar }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setUpNavigation()
    }

    private fun setUpNavigation() {
        val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.activity_main__graph__nav_host)
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationBottomBar, navController)
    }
}
```

When you load the fragment the first time it is shown like this, which is how it should be shown, and if I use the Bottom Navigation View it does well too:

[image]

But when I use the back button on my phone, here's what happens:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `HomeFragment,`setFlagsAdapter(it)` doesn't get called when you come back to this fragment. Either

change `observeOnce` to `observe`

or

Move

```
homeFragmentViewModel.getCountriesFlagLiveData().observeOnce(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        setFlagsAdapter(it)
    })
```

from `onCreateView` to

```
override fun onResume(){
    super.onResume()
    homeFragmentViewModel.getCountriesFlagLiveData().observeOnce(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        setFlagsAdapter(it)
    })
}
```

Comment: ObseerverOnce is an extension function that I had to add because the observer was entering twice each time he loaded a Fragment, and the solution I found was that. I tried to move the observer to the onResume method but it didn't work, it still doesn't show up. I've also changed ObserveOnce to Observe and it doesn't work.